# pass c_str return value of temporary object to printf

Tags: c++

Is the following piece of code valid?

> class A { string m_name; 
> public:
> string getName() { return m_name; } 
> }
>
> .....
> printf("%s", object.getName().c_str()) 
> ......

where object.getName() returns a temporary string object.

Comment: The code for `getName` would be handy.

Comment: Rolled back an edit that fundamentally changed the question to match an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The temporary string will persist for until `printf()` completes so yes, it is safe and legal.

Comment: You can even bind to a temporary, `string const & t = object.getName();` and this remains valid until the reference goes out of scope.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y: Yes, but that's not the most readable code in the world.

Comment: Re "it is safe and legal", no it's not even syntactically valid, and will not compile.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Are you nitpicking about two missing semicolons?

Comment: The fact that the code does not compile, means that it is **not the real code**. We don't know what the real code is. The presented code is certainly not valid (as this answer claims that it is), while for the real code there is no basis to claim that it's valid, or not. The part about the temporary is OK though. I also wrote that, but not drawing a conclusion about the code from it.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I wonder how anyone on this planet could possibly benefit from your reversal of my edit.

Comment: @sharptooth: Please do not edit questions to change their substance, especially when that invalidates existing answers. Nobody on this planet, and that includes you, would benefit from your edit. It constituted a particular interpretation of the question, and as you know, I for one have another interpretation (namely the literal one, is the code valid, and it's not). Instead of editing, I suggest including the interpretation in your answer. Then it's much more clear.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf This is unbelievable. The OP failed to even proper caps the question title. Do you seriously believe he intentionally omitted the two semicolons and then asked about a temporary?

Answer (score 2):

Looks valid to me, assuming get name will return a standard string object.

Answer (score 2):

Provided object.getName() returns by value, or by reference to something that remains valid:

yes

Answer (score -2):

Your code as I'm writing this:

```
class A { string m_name;
public:
string getName() { return m_name; }
}

.....
printf("%s", object.getName().c_str())
......
```

You ask, is the code valid?

No, **the code is not valid**, because

- there is a missing semicolon at the end of the class definition, and
- “....” is invalid as C++ code, and
- there is a missing semicolon at the end of the `printf` statement.

In short, the code will not compile.

Please, in the future, post code that can be compiled, so that people who want to help you can try it out for real as-is (and be sure that it is the code that you're asking about).

---

Now regarding style issues.

```
string getName() { return m_name; }
```

The lack of `const` is ungood style.

You should make the member function `const`, so that it then can be called on a `const` object.

Also, the `get` prefix is stylistically an abomination, in C++. Would you write `getSin`? The `get` prefix has a purpose in Java, but in C++ it is just visual noise and textual verbosity, i.e. it is like playing with a beach ball in a fine restaurant: what was nice on the beach (Java) is not so good in the restaurant (C++).

```
printf("%s", object.getName().c_str());
```

The `.c_str()` call is stylistically OK, because most C++ programmers do this and know that it is OK. If if it was a rarely used construction, then it could be bad style, because then other people might waste time checking whether it is formally OK. It's formally OK because the temporary lasts until the end of the *full-expression*.